# Expected';' before numeric constant

Tags: iphone, objective-c, syntax

I have the following code, but the compiler throws an error - how can I fix this?

```
NSString *a = @" b ="1.0"  "
```

Comment: Please put a properly formatted code.

Comment: heh yeah, accept my damn answer!

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape " within "  - SO it should be:

```
NSString *a = @" b =\"1.0\" ";
```